# HTML not rendered in text field content type

Tags: 9

In my content type, I have a text field that will display a string (max 200 characters) in a Bootstrap card. Due to the design, we have to allow the user to add a < br /> or \ n to add "invisible lines" to ensure content is wrapped correctly in the card.

By adding "< br /> to the field however, in twig, the < br /> is printed to screen and not HTML rendered. I have tried:

```
<p>{{content.field_copy}}</p>    
<p>{{content.field_copy|raw}}</p>
<p>{{content.field_copy|render}}</p>
```

With no affect. What other options do I have? Can this be done using a text field?

Comment: For this use case Drupal has an entire ecosystem with formatted text fields, text formats and text filters. Don't try to do this on your own. There are a lot of security considerations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's bad practice, but still

```
{{ content.field_copy.0['#context'].value|raw }}
```

Comment: This is not only bad practice, this is extremely dangerous. Drupal stores user input as it is in the database and the security of a Drupal site relies on that it is not displayed without sanitizing.